# remove the question mark from url using htaccess

Tags: apache-http-server, url, htaccess

i have tried to remove the index.php from url
    but the problem is I'm seeing an ugly question mark in the beginning of the url
    how can i get rid of it

This is the code i have used in htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule \.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$ /public/404.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php($|\ |\?)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?q=$1
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your 301 rule with this for removing `index.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]
```

Comment: i added this but this doesnt works :(

Comment: Try this in a new browser.